# Prime ideals in $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How do I obtain the result that all prime ideals in $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ are $0\times\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z\times 0$ and $R$?

1. I see that these are all prime ideals and because of $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)\in I$ we have either $(1,0)\in I$ or $(0,1)\in I$, or both. These cases now somehow yield the prime ideals listed above. But I don't understand how $(1,0)\in I\implies I=\mathbb Z\times 0$ if $(0,1)\notin I$. Obviously $\mathbb Z\times 0\subseteq I$ - the other inclusion is what I don't get.
2. Why isn't $I=\mathbb Z\times p\mathbb Z$ a prime ideal in $R$ ($p$ prime)? Isn't this correct: $R/I=(\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z)/(\mathbb Z\times p\mathbb Z)\cong\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\cong 0\times \mathbb Z_p\cong \mathbb Z_p$

Comment: Typically, the definition of prime ideal requires it not to be the whole ring.

Comment: Can you elaborate how that is relevant? Or were you just refering to $R$ being a prime ideal is unusual?

Comment: The latter, though I am more incline to think that it's a mistake in your notes.

Comment: So everything in 2 is correct and that given $I$ is prime?

Comment: I think your point 2 is correct, and $I$ is prime, yes.

Comment: $0\times \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z\times 0$ are the **minimal primes**, maybe that was it?  $R$ is never deigned to be a prime ideal of itself, in standard circumstances.

Comment: Nah, it was just a mistake. I contaced my prof. now and it is resolved. Everything that you guys said was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text of the assignment is wrong. In fact:

1. Usually (as in "this fact pops out all the time"), the definition of prime ideal of $R$ is: an ideal $P$ such that $P\ne R$ and, for all $a,b\in R$, $ab\in P$ only if $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. So $R$ should not be considered a prime ideal.
2. The prime ideals in $A\times B$ are actually $\mathfrak p\times B$ or $A\times \mathfrak q$, where $\mathfrak p,\mathfrak q$ are primes of $A$ or $B$ respectively. The reason is essentially the one you've given in (2).

Comment: Alright, I'm a little relieved. This raises another question though: I just asked it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599575/preimage-of-prime-ideals-are-prime-ideals-contradiction

Comment: $R$ itself not usually being considered a prime ideal is exactly analogous to $1$ usually not being considered a prime number.