# Preimage of prime ideals are prime ideals - contradiction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question that comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599555/prime-ideals-in-r-mathbb-z-times-mathbb-z) (only regarding commutative rings).

> Firstly, the theorem: Let $\varphi : R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. If $S$ is integral, then $\ker\varphi$ is a prime ideal of $R$.
>
> Proof. Preimages of prime ideals are prime under ring homomorphisms which follows directly from the definition. Since $S$ is integral, $(0)$ is prime and thus $\ker\varphi =\varphi^{-1}(0)$ is prime.

Now however we get the contradiction that the trivial homomorphism is not a homomorphism since $R$ can not be a prime ideal. How can this be solved? I mean, clearly $\varphi :R\to S,\ r\to 0$ is a ring homomorphism with $\ker\varphi =R$.

Comment: A ring homomorphism should send 1 to 1.

Comment: But what if $R$ doesn't have a 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two conventions for what the word "ring" means.

The relevant convention here is the one where the multiplicative unit is part of the ring structure; any ring homomorphism $\varphi : R \to S$ must have $\varphi(1_R) = 1_S$.

Comment: In my lecture we called those "unitary ring homomorphisms". Doesn't this restrict the theory quite a bit? Ring homomorphisms can be implemented on rings without a unit, can't they? Your statement basically implies that there is no ring homomorphism onto the zero ring which - I can imagine - causes a lot of trouble?

Comment: @Buh: Actually, the zero ring does have a multiplicative unit. If $Z$ is the zero ring, then $1_Z = 0_Z$.

Comment: @Buh: I wouldn't say it *restricts* the theory, but instead it *changes* the theory. The study of associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras and algebra morphisms simply has a very different flavor from the study of unital rings and unit preserving morphisms.

Comment: @Buh: But you can actually pass back and forth between them. You've mentioned one direction; in the other you can actually identify any associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra $R$ with its unitalization: the ring whose underlying set is $\mathbb{Z} \times R$ and with operations $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac, ad+bc)$.

Comment: Okay, you get me there, hehe. But still: $\varphi: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z,\ z\mapsto 0$ fullfills all requirements to be a ring homomorphism (aside the unity) so I see no reason to exclude it. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: @Buh: Because it's not a structure preserving map; it *doesn't* fulfill all the requirements to be a ring homomorphism. (where "ring" is meant as described in the post, as opposed to the alternate convention which is the one you have learned)

Comment: @Buh: A good analog for understanding this is to look at monoids and semigroups. We can consider semigroup homomorphisms between two monoids, but we only call them a *monoid* homomorphism if it preserves the unit. In fact the convention I describe is often summarized by including "$(R, 1, \cdot)$ is a monoid" among the properties.

Comment: So how is this problem here being solved in the other one of the "two" conventions you have mentioned? If one convention encounters a contradiction it's not a convention, so there must be a way this (my) theory excludes what happens here.

Comment: @Buh: I'm saying that whatever source you got this theorem from is almost surely using the convention that I describe. So that by "ring" and "ring homomorphism" the source means something different from what you thought they meant.

Comment: I can guarantee you that this is not the case. The script as well as this exercise come from the same prof. But let's get away from how somebody meant something. There must be an error in my proof above (which I did on my own) when ring homomorphisms aren't required to map $1\mapsto 1$.

Comment: @Buh: With the information you've given, I'm 95% certain that this is an issue of having definitions wrong, and 90% certain it's because of conflicting conventions for one or more of the terms involved. But since you're sure this answer is not applicable I'll delete it in a few minutes.

Comment: Why would you delete it? It issued something important! I will write a mail to my prof. now and see if that brings more clarification.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave it up.

Comment: Alright, there was a mistake in this exercise. It can be "rescued" by stating "$\ker$ is either a prime ideal or the whole ring $R$".